# Why does the Bourne shell printf iterate over a %s argument?

Tags: unix, shell

What's going on here?

printf.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
NAME="George W. Bush"
printf "Hello, %s\n" $NAME
```

Command line session:

```
$ ./printf.sh
Hello, George
Hello, W.
Hello, Bush
```

UPDATE: `printf "Hello, %s\n" "$NAME"` works. For why I'm not using `echo`, consider

echo.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
FILE="C:\tmp"
echo "Filename: $FILE"
```

Command-line:

```
$ ./echo.sh
Filename: C:    mp
```

The [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) says, "New applications are encouraged to use `printf` instead of `echo`" (for this and other reasons).

Comment: bash builtin echo doesn't do \ replacement by default, but POSIX shell (e.g. dash) echo does, as your link to the spec indicates.  Since you're using a shell anyway, you could just printf "Hello, $NAME\n"

Comment: Actually, using %s is probably a good habit, for security and correctness reasons.  printf will do \ replacement and other stuff to the format string, so keep variables out of it when possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your NAME variable is being substituted like this:

```
printf "Hello, %s\n" George W. Bush
```

Use this:

```
#! /bin/sh
NAME="George W. Bush"
printf "Hello, %s\n" "$NAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

is there a specific reason you are using printf or would echo work for you as well?

```
NAME="George W. Bush"
echo "Hello, "$NAME
```

results in

```
Hello, George W. Bush
```

edit:
The reason it is iterating over "George W. Bush" is because the bourne shell is space delimitted. To keep using printf you have to put $NAME in double quotes

```
printf "Hello, %s\n" "$NAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I interpret the [man page](http://www.ss64.com/bash/printf.html) is it considers the string you pass it to be an argument; if your string has spaces it thinks you are passing multiple arguments.  I believe ColinYounger is correct by surrounding the variable with quotes, which forces the shell to interpret the string as a single argument.

An alternative might be to let printf expand the variable:

```
printf "Hello, $NAME."
```

The links are for bash, but I am pretty sure the same holds for sh.

Comment: No, there's no "it thinks".  He DID pass multiple arguments, because he didn't quote the expansion of $NAME in the printf command.  The shell expanded it, then word-split it, then passed the 3 arguments to printf.  But as you say, ColinYounger has it right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of those words to be printed out on their own, use **print** instead of **printf**

**printf** takes the formatting specification and applies it to each argument that you pass in. Since you have three arguments {George, W., Bush}, it outputs the string three times using the different arguments.

Comment: print(1) is for printing a file to a printer, after checking its mime-type.  It's not a shell built-in in bash.